# How to warm a meal when camping or in the wild

Tags: food, camping

Can you give me an advice how to warm a meal which I carry in a jar or in a can when I go somewhere on camping or on tents in the wild.

I don't want to carry heavy things like gas bottles, a pan or a pot, because sometimes I have to walk a lot and don't like to have a heavy backpack.

Comment: What type of food is it? Or do you want something to work for many kinds of foods?

Comment: @michaelpri it will be good if you can find something for all types of food, but mainly interested in food with liquid sauce like soup

Answer (score 6):

A great way to do this is actively used by the US military in the MREs (Meal Ready to Eat). There are some available to regular civilian consumers.

Here is one such example: [Mountain Oven on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002T4RJ4K)

Basically, they use a bag and water to produce heat via an exothermic reaction. Basically, if you have food, and you have water and you have one of these such products, you can combine them for a surprisingly hot meal the requires no fire, cookware or otherwise.

I'm sure there are many other options, but this is the best that comes to mind. Happy Trails!

Comment: Being an air cadet myself, MRE's can be quite disgusting at times...

Comment: Agreed, but you have to admit, those heating packs are pretty awesome.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind luke-warm soup, a hand-warmer using the oxidation of iron can reach ~50°C. See [this PDF of the Undersea and Hyperbaric Medical Society](https://www.uhms.org/images/Safety-Articles/air_activated_warmers_raleig.pdf).

Another heat source is hexamethylenetetramine or "hexamine", sold in tablet form. A light-weight heater can be made from a can; see [Solid Fuel Burner](http://zenstoves.net/SolidFuelBurner.htm). This site also lists some alternative fuels, such as trioxane. Just put a can of soup on top of the can with the burning tablet. If you want to use a glass container, put a wire grid on top of the burner to spread heat a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Trail mix. Full of energy and healthy. If you do have a fire, you can save weight by boiling lake water for soup or tea instead of carrying water in. I recommend a stainless camping pot from REI or Walmart.

Comment: This is a fine answer. You may want to add more detail, but it is okay as is :) Welcome to Lifehacks S.E., if you have questions regarding policy, please visit [The Help Center](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I go winter camping too. Pull your gear in a sled, much easier than carrying it. But be prepared for a cold night. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you've opened your can and maybe removed a little bit, you can heat it on coals. It takes a long time and you need to stir, but you did say you didn't want to carry extra tools.

Note that you'll need to move it when the coals underneath get cool.